# angular-ui popover: Error when clicking link in popover after hitting BACK button

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I've got several popovers on a page that contains a link in each popover. When I open the popover and click the link I go to the correct page. Then when I click the back button in the browser and click a link in any popover I get the error:

> Cannot read property 'isOpen' of null:TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'isOpen' of null at
>   https://dev.techdynamism.com/Assessment/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:3546:34
>   at Scope.$digest
>   (https://dev.techdynamism.com/Assessment/Scripts/angularjs/angular.js:14275:36)
>   at Scope.$apply
>   (https://dev.techdynamism.com/Assessment/Scripts/angularjs/angular.js:14488:24)
>   at HTMLHtmlElement.
>   (https://dev.techdynamism.com/Assessment/Scripts/angularjs/angular.js:11351:24)
>   at HTMLHtmlElement.jQuery.event.dispatch
>   (https://dev.techdynamism.com/Assessment/Scripts/jquery/jquery.js:4430:9)
>   at HTMLHtmlElement.elemData.handle
>   (https://dev.techdynamism.com/Assessment/Scripts/jquery/jquery.js:4116:28)

If I go back to the page with the popovers by most any other means, changing the URL, through a link, or hit the back button and refresh, then I do not get the error when I click on a link.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've fixed this by editing the base angular-ui file.

Changed line 3546 from:

```
if (ttScope.isOpen) {
```

to

```
if (ttScope && ttScope.isOpen) {
```